# why same TASKLET can't execute on two core simultaneously?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt, tasklet, softirq

In linux Kernel implementation for ARM platform, deferred work in tasklet is added to percpu vec|vec_hi list.

1. now while returning from ISR execution it goes to address deferred work in softirq and tasklets.
2. now this deferred work can be taken care of here in interrupt context with IRQs enabled or there are ksoftirq threads that can process it in process context.
3. same tasklet will be executed on the same CPU as ksoftirq thread is percpu.
4. I have been seeing that in many books e.g. LDD, Robert Love's book, it's claimed that same tasklet can't be executed on two cores simultaneously?

how? can someone help me with this... If this is so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true. While the tasklet can be scheduled (i.e. tasklet execution requested) on any number of CPUs, it will only be executed on one.

The reason for this is I believe to simplify the development model: to make it easier to implement what is essentially an interrupt handler without needing to worry about races due to simultaneous execution on multiple processors -- and while not disabling other interrupts. (Obviously there are still many other opportunities for races that a driver developer needs to be aware of, but these are among the most difficult to solve.)

If you're asking about the implementation, it's actually pretty simple. In `tasklet_action`, `tasklet_trylock` is called. It uses the guaranteed-atomic function `test_and_set_bit` to set the `TASKLET_STATE_RUN` bit. This can only succeed on one processor. Hence, all other processors are prevented from executing the tasklet until the bit has been cleared -- which is only done by the processor that set it after the tasklet has completed.

EDIT:
 
Clarifying: calling `tasklet_schedule` on any number of CPUs (prior to execution) results in the tasklet being executed exactly once: on the *first* CPU that made the call. The same mechanism (`test_and_set_bit`) ensures that if the tasklet has already been scheduled on some other CPU but has not yet been executed, it will *not* be added to the tasklets-to-run queue on the later CPU (and hence won't be executed on the later CPU at all).

On the other hand, if it has already begun executing on the first CPU, the `TASKLET_STATE_SCHEDULE` bit will have been cleared (and hence may be set again), and so another call to `tasklet_schedule` ensures that the tasklet will eventually be re-executed on the later CPU, but not until after it has run to completion on the first CPU.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I understood this but my point is, I have create a tasklet and added it to hi_vec of a CPU on which my ISR came , now It will be served by a percpu thread ksoftirq, so definitely it will execute on same CPU only eachtime it get scheduled,  Now If for same ISR on some other CPU we raise the same tasklet with HI_VEC list of that core.. then same tasklet will be executing on two cores.in context of two per-cpu threads ksoftirq/x and ksoftirqx1 , Now as it is claimed that one tasklet cant be executed on two core simultaneously.  this claim is wrong, what u suggest ?

Comment: has the same concern of yours. why need to worry if the tasklet is stored in a per cpu data structure. Did you figure this out? @susheelpandey

Comment: Not sure why I didn't comment on this 7 years ago :)  The same tasklet will *not* execute at the same time on different CPUs. Also, ksoftirqd tasks are *not* normally used for executing tasklets. Normally the tasklet executes when returning from the ISR. The tasklet only runs in ksoftirqd when too many softirqs are triggered at once, or the same tasklet is triggered *while* the tasklet is still running (but again it won't run at the same time). See this reference for a good explanation http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch07lev1sec3.html

Answer (score 1):

softirqs are bottom half interrupt processing, is based on a an index based function call mechanism where the function implement the functionality of softirq.

An array of function pointer is maintained. When a softirq is registered a valid function pointer is written into the appropriate index. The index represent the 
number of the softirq, 0 being the highest priority softirq. A word is maintained as a mask for the pending softirq.

The number of softirqs currently 9 are represented by each bit of an word, when sofirqs are raised the appropriate bit in the mask are set.Next when kernel wants to run the pending softirqs it uses the masked word to identify the pending softirqs ,and  appropriate function calls are invoked using the array, whose 0th index is mapped with the 0th bit of the mask word.

Tasklets are implemented over softirqs, index 0 and index 5 of the array contains pointers to functions which handles high and normal tasklets respectively. Tasklets are identified with a structure which contains a function pointer and a state flag among other members.

Whenever tasklets are created, a structure is created, populating the function pointer with the address of the function that implements the tasklet. A link list of all such structures are maintained. 
When tasklet is scheduled, it(kernel) add a corresponding structure to the head of the link list and raise the softirq of the tasklets i.e. set the appropriate bits in the mask word.

Next when the function to handle the tasklets are invoked, it checked all elements of the link list, and invokes the function in the structure provided the state flag is not running, which indicates it already running in a processor.

Thus kernel make sure no 2 same tasklets are running in more than one processor.